# What's the difference between AWS sam build and sam package when using SAM?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-serverless, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I'm building some serverless apps and trying to use SAM. I've been going through some tutorials and some use `sam build`, while others use `sam package`.

What are the differences between these commands?  It seems like sam package is more difficult to use.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You may see some older tutorials where they were using `sam package` but the task that this command is/was performing is now built into `sam deploy` command so you don't need to perform it manually anymore.

The common order of calls today is `init` -> `build` -> `deploy`.

As for the differences between those 2, `build` preprocesses your project files locally while `package` used to zip your project, push it to S3 bucket and returned a processed template (replacing code references) that you would subsequently deploy (this zipping, pushing to s3 and deploying is now handled by `deploy` command).

Answer (score 2):

I normally do only `sam build` and deploy by `sam deploy`

1. `sam build` is to build the application locally by combine `SAM Template (YAML)` + `Application Code` together.
2. Transform the combination to `Cloud Formation Template (YAML)` + `Application Code`
3. Followed by `sam package` is to package the application to zip file and upload to S3 Bucket.
4. Lastly, Deploy the application to CloudFormation by `sam deploy` to create/execute change.